# Expensive ActiveRecord counts against Postgres are destroy performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance, activerecord

I have a couple of complex queries that, when run individually, come back in about 10 ms.

They generally take the form of ActiveRecord scopes.

However, they bring our production system to it's knees. These particular scopes are paginated in views in our application.

The offending queries are always `counts`. ActiveRecord must automatically perform counts when the data is to be paginated.

Postgres is really terrible at performing counts. In addition to this, it is obsessed with getting accurate counts. As a result, the counts create an `ExclusiveLock` on the underlying tables.

These locks cause everything in the database to get backed up, and it brings down the entire application.

Is there anything that can be done to prevent Postgres from locking every single table and index involved with these queries on a simple count?

Comment: What are you using for pagination? Kaminari has a `PaginatableWithoutCount` module to skip the count https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/blob/master/kaminari-activerecord/lib/kaminari/activerecord/active_record_relation_methods.rb#L50. If you use will_paginate maybe there's something similar.

Comment: That's a great question. I see both apps in the Gemfile in this legacy app. On looking further, the pagination code is calling ".per_page", which I believe is will_paginate. I'm going to try switching this and see what kind of yield it gives. This is great, thank you so much.